# Passing page item field value into iframe url in Oracle Apex 5

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I'm trying to create and iframe in Oracle Apex 5, it leads to an external website my company is doing business with.

The URL requires account, username and password to be passed in the URL, but that information is different for every user.

I plan on storing the login info in a custom login table and have it populate hidden fields on the iframe page with each user's information.

I'm unsure if I can, and how to, pass those variables from the page items into the URL.

the link's format is:

```
https://staging.companysite.com/match/login.do?account="account name"&username="username"&password="password"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had it correct during testing, but Apex was doing Apex things and not updating the changes.

if anyone ever runs into this issue again, here's the answer.

Make sure that the hidden fields are in the same region as the iframe you're working with and then the page item variable will be `&P100_PAGE_ITEM.`.

That resolved the issue.